# This script will not insert text into my database

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, string-formatting, discord.py, mysql-connector-python

I have this script ( below ) that will not insert text into my database no matter what I do. I can print it and then copy & paste into mysql and it works fine. Other scripts execute and store just fine. Any ideas?

```
    @client.command(pass_context=True)
async def addrule(ctx,*,rule):
    g=str(ctx.guild).replace(' ','_')
    sqluse(g)
    x="INSERT INTO rules (rule) VALUES (\"%s\")"
    val=(rule)
    mycursor.execute(x % val)
```

Comment: Remember to commit cursors. 
```mydb.commit()``` like in this example: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: Can't believe I forgot that! I'll add it and check back.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I forgot that! If you will post it as an answer I will accept it. :) You deserve it.

Comment: I'm happy to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember to save changes to your database via

```py
mydb.commit()
```

after doing permanent changes.